# MySQL Query returning way too many results than it's supposed to

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$query = "select DISTINCT user_info.`uid`, company_info.`uid`, user_info.`fname`, user_info.`lname`, user_info.`profile_pic`, company_info.`name` FROM user_info, company_info  where fname like '%$q%' or lname like '%$q%' AND company_info.`uid` = user_info.`uid` LIMIT 5";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query))){
   outputUserImage($row["profile_pic"]);
   outputUserFname($row["fname"], $row["uid"]);
   outputUserLname($row["lname"]);
   outputUserCompany($row["name"]);
}
```

This query works, however it's returning way too many results (which are duplicates) and it's slow in executing. Can someone tell me what seems to be the problem?

Comment: What part is duplicated?

Comment: Beware that DISTINCT clause is applied to the combination of ALL fields in your select query.

Answer (score 7):

I see the problem. You're calling `mysql_query()` inside a loop, over and over!

```
// Don't do this!
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query))){
//-----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Instead, perform the query first outside the loop:

```
// Do the query first
$result = mysql_query($query);
// Check that it succeeded
if ($result) {
    // Then fetch rows
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
      // Rest of loop...
    }
}
// problem with query...
else {
  echo mysql_error();
}
```

You may be running against PHP's max execution time for what would otherwise be an infinite loop as your query returns over and over again.  Always call `mysql_query()` outside the loop, and verify it completed successfully before fetching results.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your SQL query. You're doing a cartesian join, which is just returning the each table multiplied by the other number of rows....

```
select DISTINCT user_info.`uid`, company_info.`uid`, user_info.`fname`, user_info.`lname`, user_info.`profile_pic`, company_info.`name` 
  FROM user_info, company_info 
 where fname like '%$q%' 
       or lname like '%$q%' 
   AND company_info.`uid` = user_info.`uid` 
 LIMIT 5
```

You wanted this, which may help you get rid of the distinct. Notice the parenthesis around the or statement.

```
select DISTINCT user_info.`uid`, company_info.`uid`, user_info.`fname`, user_info.`lname`, user_info.`profile_pic`, company_info.`name` 
  FROM user_info, company_info 
 where company_info.`uid` = user_info.`uid` 
   and ( fname like '%$q%' 
         or lname like '%$q%' )
 LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this has to do with order of operations in your WHERE clause. AND takes precedent over OR. Try wrapping your OR'd statements in parenthesis, like this:

```
where (fname like '%$q%' or lname like '%$q%') AND company_info.`uid` = user_info.`uid` LIMIT 5";
```